# Hue service dies every few minutes

Tags: java, hadoop, hue

I have setup hue to use it to create oozie work flow on HDP2.0

I start Hue using `/etc/init.d/hue start` and I login to Hue webserver and work for a few minutes and then the server dies suddenly.

I have everything configured correctly, but I dont know why Hue service keeps crashing. Is Hue an unstable product ?

Where can I find the logs for the service while its running ?

```
sudo /etc/init.d/hue status
supervisor is stopped
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Hue](http://gethue.com) is used by hundred of organizations and is available in the main Hadoop distributions.

The root cause of the crash could be caused by an underlying Hadoop service. Could you check the Hue logs in order to know more? (default is /var/log/hue normally).

Which Hue version are you using? The latest one as today is 3.5. You should also post your logs / questions on the [Hue user list](http://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/group/hue-user) which is pretty active.

Comment: I looked at the init script and figured where the logs were. The root cause of Hue dying was that Hive config was incorrect. So the service tried to get Hue-Hive service 3 times and shut down. Surprisingly, Hue did not report this in "check for misconfiguration" page. I am using Hue provided by HDP (Hortonworks) 2.0, which is 2.3

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to be checked is all the permission of the keytab **hue.service.keytab** indside **/etc/security/keytabs**.

They should be as follows:
-r--r----- 1 root      hadoop 340 Jun 17 03:29 hue.service.keytab.
**Note** :- The above keytab should not have the write permission.

Also kerberos section in hue.ini file which is located at /etc/hue/conf should be properly configured according to your need.